# Working with decimal numbers in PHP

Tags: php, floating-point, decimal

I want to somehow round the numbers for a rating system in PHP like this:

```
4.6667 = 4.6

5.0001 = 5.0
```

Is there any way to do that? (BTW, I read the data from a database.)

Comment: Try googling for "php round"... First hit: http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php EDIT: by the way, why do you want 5.0001 to be round up to 5.1 and 5.6667 down to 5.6?

Comment: I have no idea how you've got those results from those inputs. Can you describe how you want this rounding system to work? Why do you want to round 5.0001 up to 5.1, but 4.6667 down to 4.6?

Comment: I want it for rating system in my site, for example if a user rates the content 4 out of 5 , it will be added to the other ratings and then the average will be calculated. This numbers (5.0001 and 4.6666) was examples

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not conforming to any single rule. For example:

```
4.6667 = 4.6
5.0001 = 5.1
```

See these functions anyway:

**[round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)**
**[ceil](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php)**
**[floor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php)**

And **[number_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)**.

Comment: sorry , it was a typing mistake, I meant : 5.0001=5.0

Comment: @The Worst Shady: ok, you need the `round` function there.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
echo round(1.45667, 2);
```

The number "2" is how many decimal places you want.

This is output 1.46.